# How to link 2 java class together with displaying menu in android studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLE4g.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnAjo.png)   How can i link my lesson1 class with chapter1 class together?

```
package com.example.liew.minnanonihongo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class Lesson1 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    // find the view that show the numbers category
    final TextView Chapter1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chapter1);
    Chapter1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent Chapter1Intent = new Intent(Lesson1.this, Chapter1.class);
            startActivity(Chapter1Intent);
        }
    });


    }
}
```

This is my Chapter1, which is display nothing... how can i link this 2 java class together without causing crash?
     package com.example.liew.minnanonihongo;

```
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;



public class Chapter1 extends AppCompatActivity {
}


enter code here
```

Comment: what do you mean by: link them together?

Comment: yaa what do you mean by: link them together?

Comment: hmm, sorry guys.. i m still a beginner to android studio... i got a mainactivity.xml as menu, and when i clicked lesson1 , it will go to chapter1,and when i clicked chapter1 , it will display the info... but my code seem got problem, it causing error and it will redicect back to my first page of menu

Comment: can you upload the stack trace of the error received?

Comment: is your Chapter1 Activity defined in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @gabodroid i declared it in java class under my package

Comment: I meant something like this:
`...
<application
  ...>
    <activity android:name="Lesson1" ... />
    <activity android:name="Chapter1" ... />
    ...
</application>
...`

Comment: @gabodroid Thanks man... i forgot declare at manifest.xml.. u solved my problem !